# How to find a cut set of edges in a graph in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph

In R, there is the `minimum.size.separators` function from *igraph* package, that find all **vertex** sets of minimal size whose removal separates the graph into more components.

What I want to know is if there is something equivalent in R for edges, i.e., if there is an equivalent function that find all **EDGES** sets of minimal size whose removal separates the graph into more components??